# How to get multiline paragraph titles?

Tags: paragraphs, rendering

I search a way to got with the following code:

```
 \paragraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
 consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.
```

A rendering like this:

[image]

I am certain I find it somewhere but I can’t find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eqparbox} \usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[wrap]{\bfseries\normalsize}{}{0}{\eqparbox[t][\dimexpr\height-1\baselineskip]{T}}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Lorem ipsum\\ dolor sit amet\\consectetur}
adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Added:**
Two different layouts for a formatting without manual line breaks in the title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[drop]{\bfseries\normalsize}{}{0}{\raggedright\parbox[t][\dimexpr\height-1\baselineskip]{0.2\textwidth}}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0.2\textwidth}{3.25ex plus1ex minus.2ex}{0.75em}%}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.

\bigskip
A variant:

\titleformat{\paragraph}[drop]{\bfseries\normalsize}{}{0}{\raggedright\parbox[t]{0.2\textwidth}}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0.2\textwidth}{3.25ex plus1ex minus.2ex}{\parindent}%}

\paragraph{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Added (22/03/2019)**:

If you want the normal paragraph layout when there is no title, you can use the `explicit` option for `titlesec` and the `numberless` key with a different style for `\paragraph*, with this modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eqparbox, xifthen, etoolbox} 

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\titleformat{name=\paragraph}[wrap]{\bfseries\normalsize}{}{0pt}{\eqparbox[t][\dimexpr\height-1\baselineskip]{T}{#1}}
\titleformat{name=\paragraph, numberless}[runin]{\bfseries\normalsize}{}{0pt}{}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Lorem ipsum\\ dolor sit amet}
adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendre

 \paragraph*{}
 Adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.rit.

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It’s not exactly what I expect. To get multi-lines, you explicitly put `\\` on the paragraph title. However, it have to automatically return to the line when the text of the paragraph title reach ~1/5 of the text width.

Comment: @fauve: I've just added two variants for what you want. Yous can have manual line breaks in case the automatic line breaks don't yield a nice result.

Comment: That’s good! But, I have only one question again. How to align in the left? I see in your code `\raggedright` but it seems not working.

Comment: But it *is* left-aligned! Change `0.2\textwidth` to   `0.3\textwidth`  and you'll see it.

Comment: I have just one question to make the answer as checked: When the paragraph contain no title (like `\paragraph{}`) I still have a very wide indent with no noting. How to make this behaviour only work when `\paragraph{}` is called with a paragraph’s title?

Comment: Do you mean that, without a title, you'd like to have no indent or a normal paragraph indent, and no shorter line except maybe the first?

Comment: Without title, I just want to get normal behavior (normal indent, normal line). As if it was no customizing.

Comment: @fauve: I've posted a new code. Please see if it's fine for you.